# Android ROTATION_VECTOR sensor to local axis rotation

Tags: android, android-sensors

I need to extract rotation of an Android device about the device Z-axis [image: Android axes]

I am currently using the ROTATION_VECTOR sensor and the following code, where `rotVec` is cloned from the `values` member of the `SensorEvent`:

```
float[] q = new float[4];
float[] globalRot = new float[9];
float[] localRot = new float[9];
float[] euler = new float[3];
SensorManager.getQuaternionFromVector(q, rotVec);
SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(globalRot,q);
SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(globalRot, SensorManager.AXIS_Y, SensorManager.AXIS_Z, localRot);
SensorManager.getOrientation(localRot, euler);
float rotation = euler[1];
```

As the device gets closer to flat, the value reported drifts from the true value. Also, the value is inverted after +- 90 degrees (0 is defined as Y pointing straight up).

What am I doing wrong, and what calls should I be using?

Comment: Euler[1] is not the rotation about the device z-axis, it is the rotation about the device y-axis in your picture.

Comment: Shouldn't the remapCoordinateSystem call change that? The value I am getting is very certainly the z rotation.

Comment: What do you really want to do?

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish the same thing too. Basically i'd need to compute the Euler angle of the z axes. @HoanNguyen do you know how to compute that?

Comment: @Andrea Baccega Do you want to calculate the direction of the back camera?

Comment: @HoanNguyen I want the euler angle that could be used to control the steering amount on a car game. That should be accomplished by getting the rotation of the Z axis.

Comment: @AndreaBaccega What is the orientation of your device?